# VBA: runtime error 55 - file already open (by using a FileDialog)

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, runtime-error, text-files

In VBA Ms Access, I import a txt file parsing it line by line.

I use a FileDialog so the user can choose the file to import, but when I open the file to read it, I obtain a runtime error 55 - file already open.

The cose is:

```
Dim openDialog As FileDialog

Set openDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
On Error GoTo DoNothing
With openDialog
   .title = "Import"
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
   .Show
End With

FName = openDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
'Close FName

Open FName For Input Access Read As #1
On Error GoTo DoNothing
```

Instead, if I use Close Fname, there are no runtime errors, but the import doesn't work (the code for the import is right, 'cause it works when I hard code the namefile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you have the filename, drop the dialog box handler with:

```
Set openDialog = Nothing
```